# distinguish what caused mkdir error

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

PHP's `mkdir` returns `false` on failure. Failure can be:

- Folder already exists
- Some other error, permissions error perhaps?

Is there a way to distinguish whether the failure occurred for one reason and not the other? I'd like my script to be able to continue operation if `mkdir` returns `false` as long as the folder already exists, but handle it otherwise if it was some other error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just check if the directory exists using [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/is_dir) once `mkdir()` fails.

This will tell you if the directory exists, however it may not be conclusive, as permissions might also prevent you from checking this (I believe the parent directories need the `+x` permission in order to traverse into subdirectories).

Comment: I would use `is_dir()` _before_ `mkdir()`. If the directory already exists then you can forgo trying to create it. It's a micro-optimization, but I believe it makes the code more clear. "if not is_dir, then mkdir".